# Python regex matches string it shouldn't

Tags: python, regex

I'm totally lost at how this regex matches this string in python. Could someone make sense of it please?

```
import re
regex = "^PHP/5.\\{3|2\\}.\\{1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0\\}\\{1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0\\}$"
ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)'
re.compile(regex).search(ua)
```

The regex starts with `PHP`, while the string does not. Shouldn't that simply disqualify a match from happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need grouping (preferably non-capturing) for your alternation:

```
PHP/5.\\{(?:3|2)\\}.\\{(?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0)\\}\\{(?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0)\\}$
         ^^    ^       ^^                    ^      ^^                    ^
```

Other wise you will be alternating the entire expression:

- `PHP/5.\\{3` *or*
- `2` *or*
- `\\}.\\{1` *or*
- `2` *or*
- `3` *or*
- `4` *or*
- `5` ***match found!***

---

<sup>*Think [PEMDAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) and nested conditionals (`if(a && (b || c)) { }`).*</sup>

Comment: Thanks for helping me hit 10k rep! :)

Answer (score 4):

Your RegEx fails, because `|` plays an important role here. So, your string is matched for items, like this

- `^PHP/5.\\{3`
- `2\\}.\\{`

and so on. Since the or matches `5` in `4|5|6`, it actually matches the `5` in `Mozilla/5.0`.

You can see online demo and explanation for the same, [here](http://regex101.com/r/yI6fE4/1).

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/PKfMxb-9b7z2dhQw)